# How to create our own wifi hotspot in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

How to create our own wifi hotspot. I need some android devices connect to my device(hotspot) through wifi.I need to perform transfering of data to these devices through a client.How to do it?

Comment: you have to mark a answer as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what Android Version runs on your devices? Android 2.2 brings the built-in feature of Wifi-tethering.

HTC has also a WIFI tethering App, which is called WIFI-Hotspot.

If it is not available on your phone, you can use this app:
http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/
Beforehand you have to root your phone to use this App. This is no problem with unrevoke tool.

Comment: I suggest to use this: http://unrevoked.com/recovery/  But there are also Apps on the market, which can root your phone. But I have never tried them out. Unrevoke is very is to use. Just one click ;)

Answer (score 0):

On my Dell Streak (running 2.2.2 StreakDroid), I just go to Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Tethering & portable Hotspot ,and then check "portable Wi-fi Hotspot"

You can also check out PDANet

http://junefabrics.com/android/

Comment: I have a Toshiba Folio 100 and a HTC wildfire mobile... And there arent any option for tethering and portable hotspot.